# Trying to simulate label click

Tags: jquery, jquery-events, event-capturing

Why doesn't this work? The label is inside the `.item` parent. I don't want to put it outside of block elements as it wouldn't be valid.

So I'm trying to simulate a label click:

```
$(".item").click(function(){
    $(this).find("label").click();
});
```

Edit: It's supposed to trigger the label and check a radio.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".item").click(function() {
            $(this).find("label").click();
        });
    }); 
</script>


<div class="item">
    <h4>Item</h4>
    <ul>                
        <li>Description</li>
    </ul>
     <div class="radio-container">
        <div class="radio-stack">
            <input type="radio" class="styled" id="item1">
        </div>
        <label for="item1">$100</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you please show your html code ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since this label is attached to some input (using the `for` attribute), you could try something like:

```
var inputID = $(this).find("label").attr("for");
$('#' + inputID).click();
```

However you should be careful: since your input is **inside** the div with the `.item` class, simulating a click in the radio will trigger your custom handler again, causing an infinite loop. If possible, just set the radio `checked` attribute to `true` instead of simulating a click:

```
$('#' + inputID).attr("checked",true);
```

(Working example at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/X7AR4/))

Otherwise, you'll need to find a way to exclude that radio from the `.item` selector to avoid that infinite loop.

**Update:** after struggling a little with `not` selectors, unsuccessfully, I came up with a quick and dirty hack: use a global (to the `ready` closure) variable to control whether or not a simulated click is happening:

```
var updating = false;
$(".item").click(function() {
    if ( !updating ) {
        var inputID = $(this).find("label").attr("for");
        updating = true;
        $('#' + inputID).click();
        updating = false;
    }
});
```

Working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/X7AR4/2/). IMO Ayman Safadi's answer is better, but if you have trouble making it work cross-browsers this alternative could be used as a starting point.

Comment: Checking the radio directly was my first idea. But since I use http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/custom-form-elements.js to style my radios it only seems to check it on a second click, that's why I tried to simulate the label click. Now I know why the label idea wasn't working at least.

Comment: Ayman Safadi's answer should work better then, but if you still have trouble (for instance, if `stopPropagation` prevents something else in your radio to work) check my updated answer.

Comment: This solves the cross browser issues, so I'm marking this one as the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

To strictly answer your question, it's not working because it's causing an infinite loop of "clicks", and your browser just kills the event silently.

Run this demo, and look at your JS console: http://jsfiddle.net/bRyR3/

The `div` is [capturing](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html#link2) the `label` click event. In other words, JavaScript interprets your logic like this:

> When you click on `.item`, trigger the `label` "`click`" event.
>
> `label` is inside `.item`, therefore if `label` is clicked, so is `.item`.
>
> When you click on `.item`, trigger the `label` "`click`" event.
>
> `label` is inside `.item`, therefore if `label` is clicked, so is `.item`.
>
> When you click on `.item`, trigger the `label` "`click`" event.
>
> `label` is inside `.item`, therefore if `label` is clicked, so is `.item`.
>
> etc...

Working on actual solution.

---

### Solution

```
$('.item').on('click', function(e) {
    console.log('click');
    $('label', $(this)).trigger('click');
});

$('.item label').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

​
This will stop `.item` from capturing `label`'s `click` event.

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bRyR3/1/

Comment: So that's why FF crashes... The actual solution could be very easy - putting the label outside .item. Not perfect but I could work with that.

Comment: @domino, I just added a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Since this question & answer pops up when looking for a solution, there is a third way to solve this issue:

JQuery allows for custom parameters to be sent to the on() event handlers, by using trigger()

See https://api.jquery.com/trigger/

This means, it's possible to avoid an endless loop by simply telling the event handler that the current event is 'artificial':

```
$( document ).on( 'click touch', '.item', function( event, artificial ) {
     if( artificial ) return;
     
     $(this).find("label").trigger( 'click', [ true ] );
} );
```

This has the advantage of not stopping propagation (or relying on it), while also not fumbling around with different input types (checkboxes, radios, texts, etc). It just simulates a click on the label without any additional work on our side or any endless loops.